# Is there a way to use lists as arguments for functions in TI-Basic?

Tags: ti-basic, ti-nspire

I am making a function in my TI-nspire CS II CAS to calculate the equivalent resistance of a resistors in parallel, with this formula:
[Parallel of resistors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6orRh.jpg)

I made a program that can do this with any number of resistors in parallel. Like this:}

```
Define prl(list)=
Prgm
:Local req
:req:=0
:For i,1,dim(list)
:  req:=req+list[i]^(−1)
:EndFor
:Disp req^(−1)
:EndPrgm
```

However, I realised that I can't do operations with it such as

```
3+prl({4,6,7})
```

,since this is a program and not a function. I tried to just copy and paste the program into a function:

```
Define pr(list)=
Func
:Local req
:req:=0
:For i,1,dim(list)
:  req:=req+list[i]^(−1)
:EndFor
:Return req^(−1)
:EndFunc
```

But it gives me the error 'Invalid in a function or current expression'. The point of the list is so that the program does the job no matter the number of resistors I want to input, but apparently that doesn't work for a function. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path of least resistance is to use functions instead of programs.
Note that `sum` can be used on a list.

[image]

Comment: Nit pick: par_res(xs):=reciproc(sum(reciproc(xs)))

Comment: Good catch, Vaelus.